# Find probability of having a certain card in a hand

Tags: probability

That might be a simple one, but I am stuck... An example of what I am trying to calculate:

- We have 36 card deck (6 to Ace).
- There is a person (Bob) holding 6 unknown to me cards.
- There are 18 cards left in a deck (other went out of game)
- I know that 1 Queen card is already out, 3 are still in game.

How to calculate probability of Bob having at least one Queen? Or 2 Queens? Or all 3 Queens?

Comment: Bob holds six cards from a deck of 35 containing three Queens.  The 18 cards you mention are irrelevant, because you know nothing about them: whether they are physically in the deck or in a discard pile makes no difference.